# CSS Flexbox How to evenly space two elements with a separator

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to evenly space two HTML elements (`div`) which both contain a list of `<a>` tags/links. The container width is `600px` and there is a separator in between these two lists.

By running the snippet below you can see how the `.dropdownSection` elements are evenly sized using `flex: 1`. However, my problem is the separator (`.sectionSeparator` ) doesn't look even between the two lists?

What can I do to make it so that everything is evenly spaced, it seems like `gap: 30px` works well but the separator still isn't even, the second list is too close to the separator.

The reason I have used `position: absolute` on `.dropdownLinks` is so that the CSS hover transition does not push and cause other `divs` to be moved.

Maybe there is another way to structure this but this is my attempt.

**Note**: The grey boxes are to represent icons that would be there.

```css
#container {
  width: 600px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#listSectionContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 30px;
  gap: 30px;
}

.dropdownSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  height: 210px;
  flex: 1;
}

.sectionSeparator {
  width: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(178, 178, 178, 0.35);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.dropdownSectionTitle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #8B8792;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.dropdownSectionTitle i {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: grey;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.dropdownSectionTitle p {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdownLinks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}

.dropdownLinks a:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dropdownLinks a:link {
  color: #939393;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.dropdownLinks a:visited {
  color: #939393;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdownLinks a:hover {
  color: #7B69FE;
  padding-left: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdownLinks a:active {
  color: #939393;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="listSectionContainer">
    <div class="dropdownSection">
      <div class="dropdownSectionTitle"><i class="fas fa-book-reader"></i>
        <p>Getting Started</p>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdownLinks">
        <a href="">Introduction</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Two</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Three</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Four</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Five</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionSeparator"></div>
    <div class="dropdownSection">
      <div class="dropdownSectionTitle"><i class="fas fa-plug"></i>
        <p>Second List</p>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdownLinks">
        <a href="">Introduction</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Two</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Three</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Four</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Five</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is already evenly spaced, your text isn't long enough to fill the container so it looks like it is not evenly spaced. If you add a background colour then you will see it. There are other ways to move the item without pushing the div, you could have used `transform:translateX(..)` or do it with position relative... many ways to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation, there is nothing wrong in your code.

As you can see in the below snippet. The sections are evenly separated from the vertical line.

I have used a border for both container and the sections to understand that clearly.

```css
#container {
  width: 600px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#listSectionContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 30px;
  gap: 30px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.dropdownSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  height: 210px;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.sectionSeparator {
  width: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(178, 178, 178, 0.35);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.dropdownSectionTitle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #8B8792;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.dropdownSectionTitle i {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: grey;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.dropdownSectionTitle p {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdownLinks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}

.dropdownLinks a:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dropdownLinks a:link {
  color: #939393;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.dropdownLinks a:visited {
  color: #939393;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdownLinks a:hover {
  color: #7B69FE;
  padding-left: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdownLinks a:active {
  color: #939393;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="listSectionContainer">
    <div class="dropdownSection">
      <div class="dropdownSectionTitle"><i class="fas fa-book-reader"></i>
        <p>Getting Started</p>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdownLinks">
        <a href="">Introduction</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Two</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Three</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Four</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Five</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionSeparator"></div>
    <div class="dropdownSection">
      <div class="dropdownSectionTitle"><i class="fas fa-plug"></i>
        <p>Second List</p>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdownLinks">
        <a href="">Introduction</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Two</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Three</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Four</a>
        <a href="">Introduction Five</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```